# Location of Big Bang

Tags: big-bang-theory

Can I point to somewhere in the sky where the Big Bang happened? A pathway so to speak on where we (and our progenitor elements) came from?

Comment: There's no point in space where the Big Bang happened, because the Big Bang made space itself (and time).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such unique point, because a key element of the Big Bang model is called the "cosmological principle," which means that every point in the universe is taken as essentially equivalent to any other.  The idea there is that as the universe ages, it changes, but it changes in the same ways everywhere so there is nothing going on that distinguishes one region from another.  This is a simplifying assumption that is supported by the fact that we see no boundary to the universe, and we see no evidence that anywhere else is different from here, the differences we see appear to be due only to the fact that we are seeing farthing into the past as we look farther away.  This assumption means you could pick any point you want, point to it, and say "the Big Bang started there," and you would be no more right nor wrong than if you pointed anywhere else.